# How do I add subscripts to labels in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm doing an analysis on air pollutants using Bayesian Kernel Machine Regression, using the bkmr package in R.

https://jenfb.github.io/bkmr/overview.html

The link is to Jennifer Bobb's instructions on how to use this package. I don't think it is relevant to the issue though. What I want to do is have PM2.5, O3, and NO2 show up in my charts with the 2.5, 3, and 2 as subscripts. I'm trying to use this function and getting no luck:

```
colnames(dat) <-  c("LTE4", "$O[3]", "$PM[2.5]", "$NO[2]", "Diethyl", "Dimethyl", "age", "tmpf", "relh", "sex", "agany", "agself", "asthma")
```

When I do this what happens I just see these labels show up in the plots with with the $ and [] instead of subscripted numbers. Any ideas?

This is the full code I am using:

```
### January BKMR Analysis ###
## Hierarchical Variable Selection ##
## Updated June 6, 2022 ##

# Reading in necessary packages
library(tidyverse)
library(bkmr)

trio_semipro <- readRDS("C:/Users/Matt/OneDrive/Documents/Fresno Thesis/Thesis Code/trio_semipro.rds")

trio_semipro
dim(trio_semipro)
head(trio_semipro)

trio_semipro$log_lte4 <- log(trio_semipro$Final)

# Separating out dataframes for winter and summer to run separate models for each season
trio_semipro_w <- trio_semipro %>%
  filter(visit_month == 1)

trio_semipro_s <- trio_semipro %>%
  filter(visit_month == 2)

# Summer and Winter Dataframes
trio_semipro_w
trio_semipro_s

head(trio_semipro_w)
#view(trio_semipro_w)

dat = cbind(trio_semipro_w$log_lte4, trio_semipro_w$O3,
            trio_semipro_w$PM25, trio_semipro_w$NO2, trio_semipro_w$diethyl, trio_semipro_w$dimethyl,
            trio_semipro_w$age, trio_semipro_w$tmpf, trio_semipro_w$relh, trio_semipro_w$sex, trio_semipro_w$agriculture_anyone,
            trio_semipro_w$agriculture_self, trio_semipro_w$asthma)

head(dat)
colnames(dat) = c("LTE4", "$O[3]", "$PM[2.5]", "$NO[2]", "Diethyl", "Dimethyl", "age", "tmpf", "relh", "sex", "agany", "agself", "asthma")
dat = as.data.frame(dat)

dat$sex

# recode the binary variable to be 0, 1 and NA
dat$agself = dat$agself-1
dat$agself[which(dat$agself==2)]=NA

dat$agself

# recode sex variable
dat$sex = dat$sex -1

# recode agany variable
dat$agany = dat$agany - 1
dat$agany[which(dat$agany==2)]=NA

#recode asthma variable
dat$asthma = dat$asthma - 1
dat$asthma[which(dat$asthma==2)]=NA


dat$asthma
dat$sex

dat$agany
# good

head(dat)

complete_dat = dat[-which(apply(dat, 1, anyNA)),]
dim(complete_dat)

# Fit BKMR

zscaled <- apply(complete_dat[,(2:6)], 2, scale)
yscaled <- scale(complete_dat$lte4)
xscaled <- cbind(scale(complete_dat[,7:9]), complete_dat[,10:13])

fit_bkmr = kmbayes(y=yscaled, Z= zscaled, X = xscaled,
                   iter = 20000, varsel = TRUE, groups=c(1,1,1,2,2), verbose=FALSE)

plot(fit_bkmr$sigsq.eps, type = "l")

TracePlot(fit = fit_bkmr, par = "beta", comp = 4)

TracePlot(fit = fit_bkmr, par = "sigsq.eps")

TracePlot(fit = fit_bkmr, par = "r", comp = 1)

# Estimating posterior inclusion probabilities

ExtractPIPs(fit_bkmr)

# Estimating h

y <- yscaled

Z <- zscaled

X <- xscaled


med_vals <- apply(Z, 2, median)
Znew <- matrix(med_vals, nrow = 1)

# Summarize model output

pred.resp.univar <- PredictorResponseUnivar(fit = fit_bkmr)


library(ggplot2) # Using ggplot to plot cross sections of h
ggplot(pred.resp.univar, aes(z, est, ymin = est - 1.96*se, ymax = est + 1.96*se)) +  
  geom_smooth(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lty = 5, col = "red2", alpha = 0.4) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, nrow = 1) + 
  ylab("h(z)") 

# visualze the bivarate exposure-response function for two predictors, where
# all of the other predictors are fixed at a particular percentile.
pred.resp.bivar <- PredictorResponseBivar(fit = fit_bkmr, min.plot.dist = 1)

ggplot(pred.resp.bivar, aes(z1, z2, fill = est)) +
  geom_raster() +
  facet_grid(variable2 ~ variable1) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#0000FFFF","#FFFFFFFF","#FF0000FF")) +
  xlab("expos1") +
  ylab("expos2") +
  ggtitle("h(expos1, expos2)")
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual code you are using to plot please Matt? There are different plotting systems in R, each with their own rules and syntax. Even the linked example shows different plotting methods. Details matter here.

Comment: Can you give a (dummy) example, that you think would work, using these labels? At the moment, we don't know how you are trying to use them and what kind of labels they should be (e.g. legend, axis, `geom_text()`, `annotate()` etc.)

Comment: Thanks Allan Cameron and teunbrand. I've added the full code to the end of my original comment. Let me know if there is anything else you need that would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: What label are you referring to? An axis label? A point label? If you want to to use `[]` for subscripts, you have to include the function that recognizes these characters. Chances are you won't be able to pass them in s traditional manner. You may have to use a `scale_` to do it. For example, `scale_x_discrete(labels = c(bquote("cyl"[4]), bquote("cyl"^6), bquote("cyl"^8[8])))`

Comment: @Matt, you should include code that others can run.  Then they'll be able to show you the necessary modifications to get it to work in your problem.  Since we don't have your `trio_semipro.rds` file, we can't run what you've already posted.  It's also helpful if you remove everything that isn't related to your question.